# encrypted password file with emacs & gpg

Tags: gpg

I want to keep all my passwords and logins in a gpg-encrypted file, that I want to access using emacs in the terminal on ubuntu.

I want to be prompted for the 'master' password when opening the file, but not when saving it. I don't want to use anything like a 'keyring'.

I managed to almost achieve my desired setup by following the instructions [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG), the only problem being that I have to enter the password twice when saving the file. The problem is that I fear that when accidentally entering the password incorrectly twice, I could lock myself out of my password file forever.

Is there a way not to be prompted for the password when saving, or alternatively for the save-password to be rejected when its hash doesn't match the password that I opened the file with?

Comment: There are many suggestions in the page you linked - it would be helpful to include exactly what code you have in your init.

Answer (score 1):

I remember struggling with this for quite some time.  Like you, I'm using public/private key with a pass phrase, **not** symmetric encryption.

What works is the following:

```lisp
;; let's get encryption established
(require 'epa-file)
(epa-file-enable)
(setq epg-pinentry-mode 'loopback)
(require 'org-crypt)
(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)
```

I do **not** unset `GPG_AGENT_INFO`.  You should set `epg-gpg-program` if `gpg` is not in your `$PATH` by default.

Setting `epg-pinentry-mode` to `loopback` is especially valuable to allow Emacs to query passphrase rather than external programs which might block the window or not work properly in containers and so forth.